# Are all principal $\mathbb{G}_a$-bundles trivial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, principal-bundles

I am considering the group scheme $\mathbb{G}_a:=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[x])$, the additive group.

I happen to know that the classifying space for $(\mathbb{R},+)$ is a singleton, which means topologically every principal $\mathbb{R}$-bundle is trivial. Then I want to know about the algebro-geometric analogue.

My questions are:

1. Are all principal $\mathbb{G}_a$-bundles trivial? Or what is the stack $[*/\mathbb{G}_a]$?
2. If the answer is negative, can you give an example of non-trivial principal $\mathbb{G}_a$-bundle?
3. If we ask for $\mathbb{G}_a\times S$ for a scheme $S$, do answers change?

Comment: The set of $G_a$ bundles on scheme $S$ is given by the cohomology group $H^1(S,{\cal O}_S)$, so there are many examples of non trivial $G_a$-bundles.

Comment: Eg on an elliptic curve, there are many non trivial $G_a$-bundles.

Answer (score 4):

Let
$$
X = (\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1) \setminus \Delta,
$$
where $\Delta$ is the diagonal. Then the projection $X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ is a nontrivial principal $\mathbb{G}_a$-bundle.

Comment: Can you be more specific on the $\mathbb{G}_a$-action on $X$?

Comment: I think this is a ${\cal O}(1)$-bundle, not a $G_a={\cal O}_{{\bf P}^1}$-bundle. So it is locally a $G_a$-bundle, but not globally.

Comment: Yes, @DamianRössler is correct, this is not a constant $\mathbb{G}_a$-torsor (though, I think, this is an $\mathcal{O}(-2)$-bundle, not an $\mathcal{O}(1)$-bundle).

Comment: @Sasha I'm confused. How is this a $\mathbb{G}_a$-torsor?(I agree that it defines a line bundle without a section. But there is no global action of $\mathbb{G}_a$ on $X$ as far as I can tell.)

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar: Yes, it is not, and this is precisely what Damian Rössler pointed out and I agreed with in my previous comment.

Comment: @Sasha Sorry, not sure how I missed that. :)